# How to I use replaceAll method with stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Hello I have a these field in db:

```
 String abcTitlename;
 String abcTitlepage;
```

And I want to get these field from entity, But I want to use without 'abc' prefix.
Example

my field is abcTittlename name but I want to get this tittlename.

Could I get these field with filter? Could I do this using replaceAll method? like this:

```
 .filter(field -> field.getName().replaceAll("abc","")
```

my fully code is :

```
            stream = stream.filter(e -> ((DbFields) e).getIscomputed().equals(0));
        }
        return stream.map(e -> ((DbFields) e).getFieldname().toLowerCase(Locale.US)).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    }
```

And I have DbFields class , that has getFieldName(),getFieldtype() vs methods.

How to add this line to this code

```
stream = stream.map(e -> ((DbFields) e).getFieldname().replace("abc", ""));
```

Help me,please..

Comment: To get what after ? a List of the Fields ? a list of String ?

Comment: what exactly is `field`? Post a [mcve]

Comment: As you show it, that's a single string. So there is no need in using streams. Streams are meant to be used for a _stream_ of data( a list for example).

Comment: a List of the fields @azro

Answer (score 2):

How about this,

```
.map(field -> field.getName().replaceAll("abc","") )
```

A more generic example can be given as this.

```
Set<String> replacedList = strList.stream()
    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("abc", ""))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

You will have to use `map` for this purpose not `filter`.

Comment: Updated the answer to return a `Set`